# Unable to remove specific folder

Tags: windows-8

This issue has been bugging me for a long time. 
There is a folder on my drive `G:\` that used to be a Google Drive folder. After a Windows re-install I can't remove the folder.

I tried giving myself the appropriate permissions, but it didn't solve the problem.

I tried deleting it from the command line with the `RD /S /Q` and got a strange error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>RD /S /Q "G:\Documents\asd"
G:\Documents\asd\Egyetem\V.félév\Önlab  - The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The problem is that the folder actually exists. However, I could create a second folder with the same name without a problem. Still no luck.

Any suggestion would be much appropriated!

Comment: What do the ownership properties look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be several causes. [This document](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=320081) should give you some options.

The most simple would be to do:

```
RD /S /Q "\\?\G:\Documents\asd"
```

If that does not work you need to look if there are files in that directory and delete them. If they can't be delete use the same command on the prompt with `\\?\` in front of the filename.
(e.g. `DEL "\\?\G:\Documents\asd\Egyetem\V.félév\Önlab\*.*"` etc) after which you can try the `RD` again.

Does it still not work look in the [link](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=320081) i provided if there are other options and please let us know.

BTW. If you could **create a second folder with the same name** it could be that there is a space after `asd`. (2 folders with the same name is not possible in the same directory) Then you need to specify it with the `RD` like:

```
RD /S /Q "\\?\G:\Documents\asd "
```

You can check with the Windows Explorer (by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on the filename) if there is a space behind the name.

Comment: Your first solution worked like a charm. Thank you!